# How do skip blank cells for sending out emails?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a google form to send out emails to parents and coaches if students are missing work. The problem I am running into is that the sometimes the coach email is not listed because the student is not in a sport, so it has a blank cell and then the script will stop running. I just want it to skip over and continue moving down the sheet. Also is there a way that I can get a cell to confirm that it sent? like having the cell next to the email say "sent" or "error" if it fails? I'm not really concerned with this part it just would be nice. I'm really new to this. Thanks!

```
function SendCoachEmails() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Homework Hour 4.0").activate();//take off 4.0 when done with texting

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DO NOT DELETE! Parent Email Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send" (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not sent")
  } else {

    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){  // i is the current row so in this i is row 2 

    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i,12).getValue(); // 15 is the email column  
    var currentStudent = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // 4 is student name column
    var currentMessage = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); // 2 is the message column
    var currentMissingAssingment = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // 9 is the missing assingment column

    var massageBody = templateText.replace("<<Student Name>>",currentStudent).replace("<<Message>>",currentMessage).replace("<<Missing Assingment>>",currentMissingAssingment);
    var subjectLine = currentStudent +" Has Homework Hour"; // change whats in the "" to what you need the subject on the email to be

   MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, currentStudent, massageBody); // to change subject on email change "Has Homework Hour" Part//

   } 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple condition statement, i.e. check if there is an email before you send

```
if (currentEmail.trim() !== '')// check if email is not blank
   MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, currentStudent, massageBody); // to change subject on email change "Has Homework Hour" Part//
}
```